# How to get data from form using POST in django (Horizon Dashboard)?

Tags: python, django, development-environment

i'm new in development using django, and i'm trying modify an Openstack Horizon Dashboard aplication (based on django aplication).

I implements one function and now, i'm trying to do a form, but i'm having some problems with the request.

In my code i'm using the method POST

Firstly, i'm want to show in the same view what is on the form, and i'm doing like this.

```
from django import http
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django import forms


class TesteForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()

class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'visualizations/validar/index.html'

    def get_context_data(request):
        if request.POST:
            form = TesteForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save()
        else :
            form = TesteForm()
        return {'form':form}

class IndexView2(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'visualizations/validar/index.html'

    def get_context_data(request):
        text = None
        if request.POST:
        form = TesteForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                text = form.cleaned_data['name']
    else:
        form = TesteForm()
        return {'text':text,'form':form}
```

My urls.py file is like this

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from .views import IndexView
from .views import IndexView2

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'teste/',IndexView2.as_view()),
)
```

and my template is like this

```
{% block main %}
<form action="teste/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" name="OK"/>
</form>
<p>{{ texto }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I search about this on django's docs, but the django's examples aren't clear and the django's aplication just use methods, the Horizon Dashboard use class (how is in my code above)

When i execute this, an error message appears.

this message says:

```
AttributeError at /visualizations/validar/
'IndexView' object has no attribute 'POST'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/visualizations/validar/
Django Version: 1.4.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'IndexView' object has no attribute 'POST'
Exception Location:
 /home/labsc/Documentos/horizon/openstack_dashboard/dashboards/visualizations/validar/views.py in get_context_data, line 14
Python Executable:  /home/labsc/Documentos/horizon/.venv/bin/python  
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

i search about this error, but not found nothing.

if someone can help me, i'm thankful

Comment: I assume there is an indentation error at `else:` in `class IndexView2`. Probably while copying it on SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signature is wrong:

```
def get_context_data(request)
```

should be

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    request = self.request
```

Check the for [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) and the word on [dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)

Since your first argument is the `self` object, which in this case is `request`, you are getting the error.

Comment: As a complement since OP is "new in development using django" -- even if there are some exceptions (class methods, static methods), _usually_ every instance method (that is `def` in `class`) has `self` as first argument. You should check the rest of your code to see if there was no other error of that kind.

Answer (score 0):

If you read more carefully the error message, it appears that the URL was retrieved using a *GET* method. Not *POST*:

```
AttributeError at /visualizations/validar/
'IndexView' object has no attribute 'POST'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/visualizations/validar/
```

See the following link for an in deep explanation of [GET vs POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: this would not have raised an error. It would have just returned.

Comment: @karthikr You are right this is not *the* error -- just *an* error ;) I don't have Django at hand but if I'm not wrong, POST is an empty dictionary for GET requests. So, the rest of the code will "not work" once `get_context_data` signature will be fixed. Or am I saying something stupid?

Comment: You are right. It would be empty. Again, it depends on what you call "error". I am talking about the "error" that gets thrown. You are talking about programming error. Different things :)

Answer (score 0):

TemplateView by default will return a method not allowed 405 when you try to post to it. You can write your own post method for it:

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'visualizations/validar/index.html'

    def get_context_data(request):
        #define your context and return
        context = super(ContactView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #context["testing_out"] = "this is a new context var"
        return context


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        if context["form"].is_valid:
            print 'yes done'
            #save your model
            #redirect

    return super(TemplateView, self).render_to_response(context)
```

If you're going to post from a form, use FormView instead, and you can still define context as you wish by overwriting get_context_data:

from django.views.generic import TemplateView, FormView

from forms import ContactUsEmailForm

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact_us/contact_us.html'
    form_class = ContactUsEmailForm
    success_url = '.'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ContactView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #context["testing_out"] = "this is a new context var"
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        #form.send_email()
        #print "form is valid"
        return super(ContactView, self).form_valid(form)

contact_us = ContactView.as_view()
```

And urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url


urlpatterns = patterns('contact_us.views',
    url(r'^$', 'contact_us', name='contact_us'),
)
```

Hope this helps :) More on [FormsView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview).